# Download canvas as image with button

Tags: html, canvas

What is the id of this canvas: carstenschaefer.github.io/DrawerJs/examples/fullscreen I want to add download button to under this canvas. I imported the source code into vscode. I tried various download codes but none of them worked. I think I'm writing the id wrong.

```
  document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  var canva = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var image = canva.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  var filename = 'test.png';
  element.setAttribute('href', image);
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.click();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an instance of drawer

```
const drawer = new DrawerJs.Drawer(null, { ...options });
```

You can call

```
drawer.api.getCanvasAsImage()
```

To get the canvas converted to base64 which you can then use it to Post to a backend server or download it.

Took at look at [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) maybe you could try using it to help with saving.

Comment: window.alert (canvas.api.getCanvasAsImage ()); it shows the picture link in the pop up window but I did not understand how to download the picture with a button.

Comment: Heyo, if you need to log stuff you should use `console.log`. 

The return value is a base64 string, you can use `download.js` to help with saving it.